# key error in retrieving values of variable in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
VOWELS = 'aeiou'
CONSONANTS = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
HAND_SIZE = 7

SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES = {
    'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1,
    'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10
}
word = 'hi'
SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES.get(word)
```

I am supposed to get values of h + I but it keeps returning NONE or key error

Comment: You seem to not understand how python dicts work, there is no key in your dict that is 'hi', there are keys for 'h' and 'i' so you need to iterate over the word and perform the lookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer (using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)):

```
word_value = sum(SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[x] for x in word)
print(word_value)
```

Answer (score 2):

You tried to solve it by checking the word "hi" in the dictionary. But what you need to do is instead of SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES.get(word), you need to go:

```
points = 0    
for character in word:
    points += SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES.get(character)
```

Basically, what this doesn't is goes through each letter in the variable word, and works out the number of points it is worth and adds that number to the variable points. You can replace your SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES.get(word) with my code above. It should work.

You can also use list comprehension. By this I mean:

```
points = sum([SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[char] for char in word])
```

This will go through each character in word, work out its points and make a list of all the points for all the characters. It will then add up all the numbers in the list together to come up with the total points. This is more complex but looks a lot more simple and is more compact.

I hope this helps.